# Python selenium string to int

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

I've tried most of the examples on stackoverflow but I can't find a way.
I have two questions, how do I make a string into a text..

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("currency-chaos")
numberOfItems = 1
for post in posts:
    numberOfItems = numberOfItems + 1
    print(numberOfItems)
    print(post.text)
```

and how do I remove a letter from the text, then transfer it into an int?

Comment: Could you show what is your current output and the desired one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to remove the non digit characters and then parse the number with `float` :

```
import re

value = float(re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", post.text))
print("value: %s" % value)
```